# OpenCV VideoCapture can't open file, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.1

I am compiling on Ubuntu 14.04 using OpenCV 3.1. When trying to open a video file it gives this error:

> "Cannot open the video file"

I installed everything i could install : ffmpeg etc. Haven't found a solution checking out similar questions on StackOF.

What do ?

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
```

Where argv[1] is the file name in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ posted

Comment: can you tell me what is argv[1]?

Comment: argv[1] is a pointer to a string representing the file name i want to open @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: try passing full qualified path as `argv[1]`.

Comment: jap, I can guess, but i want to know, is that string holding empty spaces?

Comment: @ZdaR i tried, doesn't work

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ no spaces : "4.avi"

Comment: hardcode the file path!!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ i did, still doesn't work

Comment: Try `cv::VideoCapture("/tmp/thing.avi");` and, failing that, change `.avi` to `.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

In case your constructor is failing, you may want to use the *.open()* method. So, if you want to open a file that is called "myVideo.mp4" that is in the folder of your project, you would do the following:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("myVideo.mp4");
```

For more detailed informations about this method, check this [documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#af3b71a7c0c459704ed75568a01290457)
Also, the book Learning OpenCV 3, from the O'Rilley media, on page 26 gives you a good example. Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/miguelrochajr/98da3cfaf129207fa7f42a1380debaea) that I made to give you as an example.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  cv::VideoCapture cap;
  cap.open("myVideo.mp4" );
  cv::namedWindow( "myVideo", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::Mat frame;
  while(true) {
    cap >> frame;
    if( frame.empty() ){
      std::cout << "Could not load the video frames. \n";
      break;
    }
    cv::imshow( "myVideo", frame );
    if( cv::waitKey(27) >= 0 ){
      std::cout << "Escape pressed \n";
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```